# How can I calculate all results (3) of a cube root?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, roots-of-unity

According to Wikipedia and Wolfram Alpha, a cube root $n^{\frac{1}{3}}$ has three results: one real number and two complex, if $n$ is a real number; and three complex numbers if $n$ is a complex.

Most of calculators returns only the principal root, but not the other two results. Is there a way to calculate the two remaining?

Comment: Keyword: primitive third root of unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way .e.g. First let $x^3=1$, thus
$x^3-1=0$, now convert this to the form $(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=0$ solving first bracket will give you real cube root and the second one will give the imaginary cube roots.

Answer (score 2):

Just multiply your root by $e^{2i\pi/3}$ and $e^{-2i\pi/3}$.

For example : solve $x^3=8$. A trivial root is 2, therefore the roots will be
$$
2\quad
2\, e^{2i\pi/3}\quad
2\, e^{-2i\pi/3}.
$$
If you want to solve $x^3=-i$, a simple root is $e^{-i\pi/6}$ (this because $-i=e^{-i\pi/2}$), therefore the roots are
$$
e^{-i\pi/6}\quad
e^{-i\pi/6}\, e^{2i\pi/3}= e^{i\pi/2}\quad 
e^{-i\pi/6},\ e^{-2i\pi/3}= e^{-5i\pi/6}.
$$

Comment: What root do you mean? Principal root? What about third root of -i?

Comment: @JulianSoto see my edited answer.